# Botframework v4: Pop up window

Tags: c#, popup, botframework

When the button is click in this chatbot this pop-up window appears. Is it possible to this on botframework v4? If yes can anyone give an example? And if not what bot language is used on the chatbot in the image? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality isn't related to a specific bot language, but it is a built-in feature of the (Facebook) Messenger Platform called the [Webview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview).

> The Messenger Platform allows you to open a standard webview, where you can load webpages inside Messenger. This lets you offer experiences and features that might be difficult to offer with message bubbles, such as picking products to buy, seats to book, or dates to reserve.

Although the Bot Builder SDK is not focused on a specific platform, it is possible to implement channel-specific functionality using custom channelData. An example for both versions of the SDK can be found here:

[Implement channel-specific functionality (version 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

[Implement channel-specific functionality (version 4)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

[Facebook Messenger Webview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview)

Comment: I see. Thank you. Do you also know what it is called the "pinned-like" buttons on messenger UI? The hamburger on the bottom left of the picture.